# UTF-8 encoding not working with data parsed from DBpedia using RDFLib in Python 2

Tags: python, utf-8, dbpedia, linked-data, rdflib

I have the following code to parse data from DBpedia output and add it to an RDFLib graph:

```
for index, value in enumerate(output['results']['bindings']): 
    #The encoding is necessary to parse non-English characters
    subj_raw = '<' + value['s']['value'].encode('utf-8') + '>'
    subj_refined = URIRef(subj_raw)
    pred_raw = '<' + value['p']['value'].encode('utf-8') + '>'
    pred_refined = URIRef(pred_raw)
    if 'http' in value['o']['value']:
        obj_raw = '<' + value['o']['value'].encode('utf-8') + '>'
        obj_refined = URIRef(obj_raw)
    else:
        obj_raw = '"' + value['o']['value'].encode('utf-8') + '"'
        obj_refined = URIRef(obj_raw)
    dataGraph.add((subj_refined,pred_refined,obj_refined))
```

Despite using `.encode('utf-8')`, the non-ASCII characters are not read (by the interpreter ?). I have read some responses on UTF-8 on SO but haven't been able to figure out a solution.

Why is my code not working? What do I need to change?

UPDATE 1:

Following are some examples of failed encoding:

```
(rdflib.term.URIRef(u"<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AS_Dragons_FC_de_l'Ou%C3%A9m%C3%A9>"),
 rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://dbpedia.org/property/ground>'),
 rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benin>'))

(rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benin>'),
 rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment>'),
 rdflib.term.URIRef(u'"O Benim, oficialmente designado como Rep\xfablica do Benim (em franc\xeas: R\xe9publique du B\xe9nin), \xe9 um pa\xeds da regi\xe3o ocidental da \xc1frica limitado a norte pelo Burkina Faso e pelo N\xedger, a leste pela Nig\xe9ria, a sul pela Enseada do Benim e a oeste pelo Togo.A capital constitucional \xe9 a cidade de Porto-Novo, mas Cotonou \xe9 a sede do governo e a maior cidade do pa\xeds. O pa\xeds tem 112 622 km\xb2 e uma popula\xe7\xe3o de quase 9 milh\xf5es de habitantes (2009)."'))

(rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Benin>'),
 rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>'),
 rdflib.term.URIRef(u'"Benin [be\u02c8ni\u02d0n] (frz. B\xe9nin [be\u02c8n\u025b\u0303]) ist ein Staat in Westafrika. Er grenzt im Westen an Togo, im Norden an Burkina Faso und Niger, im Osten an Nigeria und im S\xfcden an den Golf von Guinea, genauer die Bucht von Benin.Bis 1975 hie\xdf das Land Dahomey. Die Bezeichnung steht in Tradition zum historischen K\xf6nigreich Dahomey, das bis zur Eroberung durch die Franzosen Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts den s\xfcdlichen Teil des modernen Staates und des Nachbarstaates Togo umfasste. Beim Human Development Index steht das Land auf dem 165. Platz von 187."'))
```

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? Can you provide an example string for which the encoding or decoding fails?

Comment: I am using Python 2. Added a few examples

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the encodings you're showing? The Unicode in the 6th and 9th examples is correct, it just looks weird because Python escapes the non-ASCII stuff in the `repr` of the `unicode` string. The first term has URL encoding, not unicode encoding, but again, if you're going to interpret it as a URL, that's probably what you want.

Comment: If the goal is to get some RDF data that can be added to RDFLib graph then you can generate this data in the SPARQL query itself - using CONSTRUCT query type - https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct